# Display arrow below active navigation item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently building a portfolio site to showcase some of the work I've done whilst at university and settled on a one page design. What I'd like the site to do is as you scroll down and 'enter' the various sections, a down arrow below the navigation bar will horizontally slide across (as an animation) to below the current active section/navigation item.

What have I tried? I'll be honest, nothing. I'm not looking for an answer, though that would be nice, I just need a starting point. The main issue is that I really have no idea how to 'snap' it to be below each list item so that it is perfectly central to the text and caters for different display resolutions.

**HTML**

> ```
>   <div id="header">
>         <div class="topbar">
>         </div>
>         <div class="headbar">
>             <nav>
>                 <div class="wrapper">
>                     <ul>
>                         <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#work">Projects</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </div>
>             </nav>
>         </div>
>         <div class="shadow">
>         </div>
>         <div class="current"></div>
>     </div>
> ```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
width: 920px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

#header .topbar {
height: 10px;
background-color: #386c93;
}

#header .headbar {
height: 60px;
background: #f2f2f2;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmZmZmZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNmMmYyZjIiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxMDAlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjY2JlYmZmIiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjEiLz4KICA8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PgogIDxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZC11Y2dnLWdlbmVyYXRlZCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f2f2f2 100%, #cbebff 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#f2f2f2), color-stop(100%,#cbebff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%,#cbebff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%,#cbebff 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%,#cbebff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%,#cbebff 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cbebff',GradientType=0 );
border-bottom: 1px solid #9b9999;
}

#header .shadow {
height: 17px;
background-image: url('shadow.png');
background-repeat: none;
background-position: center;
}

#header a {
color: #5c5959;
text-decoration: none;
}

#header a:hover {
color: #0092ff;
}

#header .current {
background-image: url('nav-pointer.PNG');
height: 19px;
width: 22px;
margin-top: -18px;
margin-left: 715px;
}

#header ul{
padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
}

#header li {
font-size: 16px;
//float: left;
display: inline;
color: #5c5959;
padding: 30px;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle just to make life easier for everyone - http://jsfiddle.net/GW6CG/2/ - apologies if the CSS is a little messy, I intend to clean that up at some point.

Alternatively you can view the site live here: http://www.jonline.me.uk/dev/

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in creating this functionality from scratch. Lots of plugins have already been created to accomplish this. One is [scrollit.js](http://bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/).

Also, if you'd like to add fart noises as you scroll, check out [fartscroll.js](http://theonion.github.io/fartscroll.js/)

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thanks. The issue isn't so much the page scrolling part, I've got that, the problem is working out how to snap a downwards pointing arrow to the current active navigation link - there's a similar example to what I'm after here: http://www.cyberpowersystem.co.uk/system/FANGBOOK_Evo_HX7-100 on the gallery section.

Comment: That should be easy. Give me a second.

Comment: Yea well having read through what you've provided I guess you'd just include a background image to the active class - activeClass: 'active'?

Comment: Yes, basically. You could add the arrow in other ways, but that's an answer for another question. Making the arrow slide from one to another would be another one. I guess you don't need my help now, do you?

Comment: I'll give it a crack and see which direction I head! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something a while ago that you can easily use as a skeleton for this: **http://jsfiddle.net/LYqVk/2/**

The JQuery looks like this:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var scrollTo = $(id).offset().top;

    $('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop': scrollTo
    }, 500);
});

$(document).scroll(function () {
    highlightSection();
});

function highlightSection() {
    // Where's the scroll at?
    var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Remove highlights from all
    $('a[href*=#]').removeClass('highlighted');

    // Loop over each section
    $('#content .section').each(function () {
        // Calculate the start and end position of the section
        var sectionStart = $(this).offset().top;
        var sectionEnd = sectionStart + $(this).height();

        // If the current scroll lies between the start and the end of this section
        if (currentPosition >= sectionStart  && currentPosition < sectionEnd) {
            // Highlight the corresponding anchors
            $('a[href=#' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('highlighted');
        }
    });
};

highlightSection();
```

Have a good read of the comments in the code, hopefully they are explanatory enough but just in case they're not the basic process is this:

1. Work out where we are on the page - `.scrollTop()`
2. Loop over the `.sections`
3. If the current position lies between the top and bottom of a section, that's the one we want to highlight*

   - in your case that would be with an arrow.